# display printf output in main window in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am new to Qt programming, I have made a simple gui with a single push button. Basically I have written a program in C++ now I want to make Gui for my project. I want to display output of all printf statement in my gui. printf statements showing their output in console but I want to add something similar to console in my gui so that whenever I call printf statement it shows its result in the gui. Could you please guide me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [QLabel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html) to show your output in the GUI.

Everytime you call printf, you call [setText(...)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#text-prop) instead. Now the debug text will be shown in the text label in your GUI.

You can add several QLabels for different debug outputs, if you want.

**EDIT:**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710839/piping-standard-output-into-qlabel-in-qt-4-7) could also be of interest.

Comment: @KamilKlimek: Maybe you are processing rich text instead of plain text, I can imagine this takes more time. Try setting plain text specifically with [textFormat()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#textFormat-prop), if you only use plain text.

Comment: I am using real time operating system like xenomai, and I am using rt_printf instead of printf becuase printf is too slow. could you please let me know how can I use rt_printf in qt or alternate of doing the same thing ?

Comment: @gartenriese calling set text is slow even for plain text if you're adding another lines to it. setText will repaint whole label instead of appending new parts. Thats why it's low performance solution. Best would be something that support appending

Comment: @nabeel: Sorry, I haven't found anything else. Maybe qt is not what you want?

Comment: @KamilKlimek: Then maybe a ListView would be better?

Comment: guys please help me.let me try to make question more clear. label is working but the thing is label display data very frequently and I am unable to see all my data, like in simple C++ program when we run our program we can see the output of all printf statements in console and as the second printf statement is called the data of previous printf statement goes down and new data come up. Say if we have two printf statement then we can see two output in console but here in label if I write two qDebug statements, I can see the out of second statement only. I hope I deliver my question.

Comment: @nabeel: As I mentioned in the comment above yours, you can use a ListView. I'm pretty sure it's not faster than QLabel, but you can see all your recent outputs.

Answer (score 0):

use [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html) start your CLI program and use readData/writeData to get your information and put them into a QTextEdit

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer of my question, I have used textbrowser in gui and make a function which I call for printing my data in gui. I can not show the picture of my gui because I have less reputations.

here is the function that I have used for printing.

```
void MainWindow::print(const QString &input){

data_lab += input;//to display all data in stream
ui->label->setText(input);
ui->textBrowser->setText(data_lab);


}
```

and here is the call of function from main.

```
w.print("hellok\n");
w.print("l\n");
```

I hope this will help somebody like me.

Comment: You can also use [QTextEdit::append(const QString & text)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtextedit.html#append). That way you wont have to keep a variable that contains all the printed data, you can just append new strings to your text browser. `ui->textBrowser->append(input);`

Comment: If you're so concerned about performance, appending and re-setting text into the field is so not good.